# Cucumber + repeating steps + Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cucumber, bdd, dry

Yesterday I have started implementing cucumber tests for my Rails application. I got the initial feature right. But when I write features I could see some are repeating

Example: login feature (scenario).

I'm thinking of how to make those steps DRY, by calling those features inside other features.

I found these article also useful

- http://blog.mattwynne.net/2008/11/14/dry-up-your-cucumber-steps/
- http://collectiveidea.com/blog/archives/2011/06/09/reusable-cucumber-steps/

I'm new to Cucumber, how can I make a start on implementing repeating features?

I'm using Rails 3.

### Edit

I have the following scenario to login:

```
Scenario: login
         Given a user that is "test"
         When I go to the homepage
         Then I should see "Good Food"
         When I fill in "user_session_login" with "test"
         When I fill in "user_session_password" with "welcome"
         When I press "user_session_submit"
         Then I should see "Welcome test"
```

and I have another scenario to view the dashboard (initial page user sees after login):

```
Scenario: view_dashboard
         <need to add the login feature here>
         Then I should see <some link in dashboard>
```

I want to add the login feature in the view_dashboard feature, so that I don't want to repeat the login in dashboard.

Answer (score 3):

You can add a step which is called "Given a user logged in"

and add the form/login process in this step..

So you can use "Given a user logged in" in every feature...